Existence of locus of closed immersion from surjectivity of the sheaf homomorphism

Definition. A morphism $i : Z \to X$ of schemes is called a closed immersion, if the underlying continuous map is a homeomorphism between $Z$ and a closed subset of $X$, and the sheaf homomorphism $i^{\flat} : \mathcal{O}_X \to i_{*}\mathcal{O}_Z$ is surjective.

Let $f : X\to Y$ be a ( possibly finite ) morphism of schemes with $f^{\flat} : \mathcal{O}_Y \to  f_{*}\mathcal{O}_X$ be the sheaf homomorphism. My question is, if $f^{\flat}$ is surjective, then does there an open subset $V \subseteq Y$ such that $\bar{f} : f^{-1}(V) \to V$ is closed immersion? ; i.e., $\bar{f}^{\flat} : \mathcal{O}_V \to \bar{f}_{*}\mathcal{O}_{f^{-1}(V)}$ is surjective ( which is guaranteed by the surjectivity of $f^{\flat}$ since $\bar{f}^{\flat} = f^{\flat}|_V$ ) and $\bar{f}$ is the topological closed embedding ( a homeomorphism onto a closed subset of $V$ ) ? More generally, if $f^{\flat} |_V$ is surjective for some open $V \subseteq Y$, then does there an open $W \subseteq V$ such that $f^{-1}(W) \to W$ is closed immersion? If not, when?
